# All content is HTTPS, but browsers warn of HTTP mixed content

Tags: ssl, https, http

Previously Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and other browsers showed [our site](https://wisconsinwetlands.org) as fully SSL/HTTPS secure. For some reason, they now warn about mixed content.

But the content in question seems to be secure.

This only affects a subset of the images on each page. Here's one example—a footer image. The image is entered like this on the WP back-end:

```
<img src="https://widgets.guidestar.org/gximage2?o=7583405&l=v4" />
```

Firebug > Inspect Element shows:

```
<img src="https://widgets.guidestar.org/gximage2?o=7583405&l=v4">
```

Firefox > View Source shows:

```
<img src="https://widgets.guidestar.org/gximage2?o=7583405&l=v4" />
```

But Firebug > Network tab > Protocol column reports the image as:

```
HTTP/1.1
```

Chrome developer tools show the same results. What could cause this problem?

Comment: you could try going doing a db search and replace all `http://widget.guidestar.org` with `https://widget.guidestar.org`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "www.wisconsinwetlands.org" URLs redirecting to insecure "http://wisconsinwetlands.org".

The cases you have used these is in the images on the page.  Every image that is set as "https://www." redirects to the insecure version.

So while you do need to fix that and correctly configure your setup so that both "www" and non-www URLs are secure, you could quickly solve the problem by removing the www from your image URLs.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the fix and the short-term work-around. I've successfully used the work-around for our home page and donation page, to reassure year-end donors. DreamHost must have misconfigured redirection either when we added SSL or when we switched to their managed hosting.

Answer (score 2):

301 redirects are the reason.

In your site you have this image:

`https://www.wisconsinwetlands.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/mainheader7-1.jpg`

So it looks like HTTPS, but... If you go and visit that link, you'll get redirected with 301 to:

`http://wisconsinwetlands.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/mainheader7-1.jpg`

So it's not over HTTPS.

Comment: +1 Thanks -- this was a great clue that helped lead to the solution.